# Turn-off Deck.gl tooltip in Superset

Tags: css, apache-superset, deck.gl

does anbody kwno how I can modify the properties of the Deck.gl tooltip in Superset using CSS? My goad is to completely deactivate the tooltip. I tried the following which solved my problem partially:

```
.deckgl-tooltip{
  display:none;
}
```

BUT: I still see a small black square instead of the tooltip. How can I get rid of this square?

[image]

EDIT: below is a screenshot of the map and the code. When I scroll over the map, that yellowish highlighted class ('css-y3eng8') appears and it is dynamic in a sense, that it changes the class name when I move over the map.

[image]

Here is a link to the copy of outer HTML:
https://codefile.io/f/MXx4crq6R6

Comment: We may need to see the markup to help. Are you sure `deckgl-tooltip` is the highest level class on the tooltip? Seems like it might have a parent which is the black box you are seeing.

Comment: Hello @DanielBlack, thanks for quick reply. This is what I see when analyzing the page source code for tooltip:
<div class="deck-tooltip" style="z-index: 1; position: absolute; pointer-events: none; color: rgb(160, 167, 180); background-color: rgb(41, 50, 60); padding: 10px; top: 0px; left: 0px; display: none;"></div>

Comment: @DanielBlack is that code enough? I can also paste complete code

Comment: You want a css only solution? Can you share anymore of your code usage around deck.gl?

Comment: Hello @morganney, I am open to any solution which helps me to remove that black square. I editted the question with some additional information.

Comment: Can you share code showing how you are loading the map and tooltip? Otherwise there is no way to suggest fixes. Are you using react and `getTooltip`?

Comment: I‘m using the software superset, this is the path of the Deck.gl, maybe this helps: https://github.com/apache/superset/tree/master/superset-frontend/plugins/legacy-preset-chart-deckgl

Comment: Do you have access to the source code? Looks like that wraps deck gl and uses react. Should be able to find a `getTooltip` callback that can either be removed or accepts a `style` argument.

Comment: @morganney I have full access to the code, but I'm not sure where to search for the setting...

Comment: @DatamineR better if you can provide working link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your custom CSS does not point to correct element

[image]

The custom CSS should be:

```
#chart-id-182 > div > div:nth-child(2) {
  display: none;
}
```

Don't worry about `#chart-id-182`, it always be fixed for a chart

Answer (score 0):

Try **getTooltip** (Function in JavaScript).

The simple function that can be done in JavaScript;

JavaScript

```
var deckgl = new deck.DeckGL({
  // Other properties...
  getTooltip: ({object}) => object ? { // When the tooltip is hovered
    html: `${object.name}`,
    style: {
      // Some styles e.g. background: "#000"
    }
  } : (null) // Else (if not hovered)
});
```

Comment: Hello @display_name, I tried you code, but with the same result :/
I think the class is correct, because the setting affects it, before the setting it was showing a tooltip with a value, now it is just a black square.
Clearing cache also didn't help.

Comment: Hello, thank you for the suggestion. But I think this would require re-building the image, which is a problem, because the dashboard is already in production and used by many users. I would need to set it up again...